# How do you move Google Drive folders from one account to another?

Tags: google-drive

I have a domain/email `x@foo.com` with 2 folders, `photos` and `documents`, and I would like to completely delete this domain from my domain registrar, and get rid of the old email address `x@foo.com`, and have everything now live under `y@bar.com`, in the Google Drive.

Posts online say to "share" your photos from the old account to the new account. But this results in them only showing under the "shared with me" tab in the new domain's Google Drive. I can drag the folder to the regular folder section, but then it shows it as a "linked folder" icon. I would like for the files to literally be copied over to the new account. I can't upload them as it already took me 3 months 8 hours a day to upload all my high-res photos from external hard drives, I don't want to do that all over again.

How can I properly do this so when I delete my old account it won't delete the folders/files? I don't like how sharing is feeling, it doesn't seem right. How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UPDATED ANSWER

Following OP's [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/159536/how-do-you-move-google-drive-folders-from-one-account-to-another#comment145793_159540):

> This does not work: `Sorry, cannot transfer ownership to y@bar.com. Ownership can only be transferred to another user in the same organization as the current owner.`

*You may find a solution based on [Move files to shared drives](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310460)*

> When you move a file to a shared drive, the team becomes the owner of the file.

#### Please try the following

1. **Create a new Shared Drive inside your new `y@bar.com` domain**.
2. **Add the old owner** of your old `x@foo.com` files/folders **as a member to the created Shared Drive**.
3. Log-in to your old `x@foo.com` account and **move files to the Shared Drive**.
4. Log-out and log-in your new account.
5. **Find the files inside your new `y@bar.com` account Shared Drive :)**

***Note/Tip***
*I assume you have the Business or Enterprise edition of GSuite. If not, make use of the [Start your free 14-day trial today](https://workspace.google.com/signup/businessstarter/welcome) offer*

**Further reading:**
[Move content to a shared drive](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7374057)
[Best practices for shared drives](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310460)
[Get started: Drive setup guide for admins](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7658513)
[Compare G Suite Basic and Business editions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10078573)
[Transition your ​Google Workspace​​​ edition](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9522878)

---

**Original answer**

Please follow these steps

1. **Log-in** to your `x@foo.com` account
2. Choose and **right click** on your folder

[image]

3. **Share it** with your new `x@foo.com` account by making it an `editor`. Press done.
4. Following that, **right click again and change the option from `editor` to `owner`**.

[image]

5. Log-out from your `x@foo.com` account and log-in to your `y@bar.com` account.
6. **Find and enjoy the folder in the drive of your new `y@bar.com` account :)**

---

*If you want to test it first, create a new test-folder in your old account and follow the above steps.

After following these steps your test-folder will "disappear" from the old account and re-appear in your new account*

Comment: This does not work: `Sorry, cannot transfer ownership to y@bar.com. Ownership can only be transferred to another user in the same organization as the current owner.`

Comment: Please see the updated answer.